# Bypassing iOS CNA when implementing a captive portal in Linux + Apache2

Tags: apache, ios7, apache2, lighttpd, captivenetwork

I am trying to implement a captive portal using a Linux machine with Apache2.
In this situation, most OSs use the Captive Network Assistant (CNA) technique to "detect" whether they are accesing a captive portal or not (Android, Windows, OSX, iOS,...).

Well, everything works "fine" for Android and Windows devices (although they may alert you with some message like "you may require additional network information..." and stuff). The problem comes with Apple devices. It seems like iOS implementation of CNA is a bit harder, because it opens a login popup waiting for the credentials introduction...
In this way, I am not able to browse my content in Safari's main window, but in that "temporary" Safari window...

I have extensively looked after some ways of "bypassing" this iOS CNA implementation just serving a "success.html" file when convenient, and I have found that someone has succeeded using LightTPD web server, like this:

```
dir-listing.hide-dotfiles   = "enable"

# Fix for iOS7
#   It ask especially different domains without a specific URL.
#   It want to get a "success" message, to allow full system/internet access
$HTTP["useragent"] =~ "CaptiveNetworkSupport" {
    server.document-root =  "/opt/piratebox/www/library/test/"
    index-file.names        = ( "success.html" )
    dir-listing.activate    = "disable"
    server.error-handler-404 = "/success.html"
}
```

I would like to know if someone could "translate" the preceding LightTPD directives into their equivalent in Apache2, probably with some RewriteCond + RewriteRule directive...

Otherwise, if someone had achieved bypassing iOS CNA for a captive portal using Apache2, I would be very interested in reading a brief description of the process, to reproduce it on my own.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

my sample:

```
    RewriteEngine  on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^CaptiveNetworkSupport(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/tools/apple(.*) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://yourdomain/pub/apple/success.html [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in brief so that it is more useful for OP and other readers.